# Google Maps API v3 IE 11 Enterprise Mode

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am interested to know if Google Maps v3 is compatible with IE11 Enterprise Mode. I see that it is not compatible with compatibility mode but the site did not say anything about Enterprise Mode.

Comment: have you tested something on IE11 Enterprise mode?

Comment: Of course. We are testing our product on Enterprise mode. Before upgrading to the latest version of google, I would like to know if someone has tried it without wasted development time.

Comment: As of today - no it doesn't work. (v3.30.13 now the minimum gmaps js API which now denies IE8 - enterprise mode)